# PHP reading from text working fine on local machine with XAMPP, but only reading first line on server

Tags: php

I have a strange issue. I need to read lines from a TXT file and process them.
My problem is:
On my local, Windows machine, it works flawlessly with XAMPP, but at the moment I transfer it to (a probably unix based) web host, it's reading only the first line of code, or does not comply at all.

What can be a problem? I tried EOL conversion, but didn't work.

```
$file = fopen("foglalasi_adatok/foglalodb.txt", 'r');

$foglalsok = array();
$foglalas_datumLista=array();
$darabszam = 0;

while (!feof($file)) {
    $foglalasok[$darabszam] = explode(';', fgets($file));
    $temp_foglalasok_array=getBetweenDates($foglalasok[$darabszam][4], $foglalasok[$darabszam][5]);

    if(str_contains($foglalasok[$darabszam][8],"nem foglalhato")) {
        for($var=0;$var<sizeof($temp_foglalasok_array);$var++) {
            $temp_foglalasok_array[$var].="n";
        }
        
    } else if(str_contains($foglalasok[$darabszam][8],"elutasitva")) {
        for($var=0;$var<sizeof($temp_foglalasok_array);$var++) {
            $temp_foglalasok_array[$var].="f";
        }
    } else {
        for($var=1;$var<sizeof($temp_foglalasok_array)-1;$var++) {
            $temp_foglalasok_array[$var].="o";
        }
        $temp_foglalasok_array[0].="e";
        $temp_foglalasok_array[sizeof($temp_foglalasok_array)-1].="h";
    }
    $foglalas_datumLista=array_merge($foglalas_datumLista,
                                     $temp_foglalasok_array);
    $darabszam = $darabszam + 1;
}

fclose($file);
```

File is uploaded, and in same folder as on PC. (It reads the first line in one instance). Sorry for my code not being fully english.

Text file looks like this:

```
String;String;String;String;Date1;Date2;Int;String;String

Random Name;Random Address;RandomPhoneNumberAsString;random@email.address;20220101;20220528;5;comments;unavailable
Random Name2;Random Address2;RandomPhoneNumberAsString2;random2@email.address;20220812;20220818;9;comments;rejected
Random Name3;Random Address3;RandomPhoneNumberAsString3;random3@email.address;20220902;202201015;13;comments;successful
```

I just need to read them, and then put them into a calendar with some rules, but it's working completely fine on the local machine, with XAMPP, and breaks when I upload the code and the file to the hosted server.

```
function getBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate)
{
 $rangArray = [];

  $startDate = strtotime($startDate);
  $endDate = strtotime($endDate);

   for (
     $currentDate = $startDate;
     $currentDate <= $endDate;
     $currentDate += (86400)
     ) {

     $date = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate);
     $rangArray[] = $date;
       }

       return $rangArray;
       }
```

Comment: What line terminator is in the file. Windows and Unix use a different line terminator. Did you copy the file from Windows to Linux

Comment: I copied file from windows to (probably) linux, but first I changed the EOL in Notepad++ to Unix (LF). It did not work either way.

Comment: Ok that s twice you appear to NOT be sure what OS you are using on the Server. Maybe check 1 would be to make sure about that

Comment: Okay, I checked and it's Linux, with PHP 7.4

Comment: Can you give us a reasonable example of a few lines of the text file. If you have to obfiscate at least keep the fields data relevant to the code that plays with it

Comment: Can PHP version be the issue?
I just looked up the difference between the working version and the version the host provides, and I use for example array_merge() which is there in 7.4 but only for numeric keys.

Comment: Could be relevant, what versions are you using where?

Comment: And what does`getBetweenDates()` do

Comment: Local is XAMPP with PHP 8.1.6, hosted is 7.4.

Edited the question, put in the asked function

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for the help, it was version mismatch.... but there was no error message or anything. I asked for a verison change and now it works flawlessly...

Answer (score 0):

It was version mismatch.

I used some functions that were not present (or not exactly) in v7.4, and are present in 8.1 which I worked with on local machine.